# mySql apostrophe syntax

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am able to insert a value that contains apostrophe to my MySql db using the

```
 //will try to insert the word //test'testa
 $escapedWord = $mysqli->real_escape_string($word);
 $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO myTable (theWord) VALUES ('$escapedWord')";
```

The word is being inserted to the db as following:  test'testa
(As I check it manually)

However, while trying to retrieve the same value from the DB, I am getting the following error:

The query I am using is the following:

> $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable where id = '$id'";
>
> $result = $mysqli -> query($query ) or die($mysqli -> error . **LINE**);
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'testa', '1388490898000')' at line 235insert error.

What shall I use?

Comment: The error is in your mysql insert query, please post the query so that we can help you

Comment: Show the code that tries to retrieve the value.

Comment: @tony9099 not this query, the query which contains 'testa', the number and all. the insert query. Please give the query on line 235 of your php file that's doing the insert operation.

Comment: see updated question again

Comment: What is the value of $id? It appears to be the problem.

Comment: if I have a word like test'testa, shouldn't it  ???get inserted into the DB after the escaping as test\'testa

Comment: Still not the corresponding code. Since you're already using mysqli, consider investigating bound parameters / prepared statements.

Comment: That is not the correct INSERT query.  The error shows at least 2 pieces of data being inserted: 'testa', '1388490898000'

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the apostrophes. Use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or mysql_real_escape or some other possibility to solve your problem. If you do your job well, you will protect yourself against [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as well.